# Прилипание окна к краю экрана

Tags: c#, wpf

Как реализовать в WPF прилипание окна к краю экрана?
Вот такой код нашел для WinForms.
P.S. Для тех, кто не понял задания: прилипание к краю - это когда перемещаешь форму к краю, а она на определенном расстоянии примагничивается к краю. ScreenSnap в VCL это называется.

```
protected override void WndProc ( ref Message m ) {
    if (m.Msg == 0x0046 /* WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING */) {
        Rectangle workArea = SystemInformation.WorkingArea;
        Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)(IntPtr.Size * 2 + m.LParam.ToInt64()), typeof(Rectangle));

        if (rect.X <= workArea.Left + DISTANCE)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2, workArea.Left);

        if (rect.X + rect.Width >= workArea.Width - DISTANCE)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2, workArea.Right - rect.Width);

        if (rect.Y <= workArea.Top + DISTANCE)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2 + 4, workArea.Top);

        if (rect.Y + rect.Height >= workArea.Height - DISTANCE)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2 + 4, workArea.Bottom - rect.Height);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Что значит "прилипание окна к краю экрана"?

Comment: Опишите проблему более детально!

Comment: Я тут вижу ещё другую проблему: этот код берёт WorkingArea, что нормально для системы с одним экраном, но плохо для нескольких экранов, когда реально мы имеем несколько состыкованных друг с другом прямоугольников.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846732/anchor-window-to-screen-edges-in-wpf) линка на зарубежном стеке. Суть та же, что и в winforms. События просто идут из xaml-окна.