# Прилипание окна WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Я уже задавал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541472/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) по этому поводу, но решения уже есть только когда перетаскивание за заголовок окна идет. Попробовал написать свое решение, основываясь, на том коде. Вроде работает, но немного подергивается. Можете ли что-нибудь посоветовать? [Вот](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_bxeooZQB6fNlVEWGlYbmpzTlk/view?usp=sharing), если кто-то хочет проверить, как работает.

```
    private const int SnapDist = 75;

    private bool DoSnap(int pos, int edge)
    {
        int delta = pos - edge;
        return delta > 0 && delta <= SnapDist;
    }

    protected override void OnLocationChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        bool t = false;
        System.Drawing.Point Location = new System.Drawing.Point();
        Location.X = (int)Left;
        Location.Y = (int)Top;
        Screen scn = Screen.FromPoint(Location);
        if (DoSnap((int)Left, scn.WorkingArea.Left))
        {
            Left = scn.WorkingArea.Left;
            t = true;
        }

        if (DoSnap((int)Top, scn.WorkingArea.Top))
        {
            Top = scn.WorkingArea.Top;
            t = true;
        }


        if (DoSnap(scn.WorkingArea.Right, (int)(Left + Width)))
        {
            Left = scn.WorkingArea.Right - Width;
            t = true;
        }

        if (DoSnap(scn.WorkingArea.Bottom, (int)(Top + Height)))
        {
            Top = scn.WorkingArea.Bottom - Height;
            t = true;
        }

        if (!t) base.OnLocationChanged(e);

    }
```