# Прикрепление окна к краю монитора c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Суть вопроса такова: хочу сделать как в некоторых программах - при перемещении окна к краю монитора, форма должна примагничиваться к краю монитора. Как такое реализовывается? Примеры: аимп плеер, клиент стим. Там когда подводишь форму к краю, она примагничивается к краям. Подскажите пожалуйста как такое реализовать.

Comment: реагируете на перемещение окна. Когда позиция приближается к границе - сами "додвигаете" к границе. И аналогично, не даете отодвинуть на какое то минимальное расстояние, возвращаете назад.

Comment: @Monk это понятно, но хотелось бы увидеть минимальный пример этой реализации. Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Прилипание с возможностью задвигать окно за экран:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0046 /* WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING */)
    {
        Rectangle workArea = SystemInformation.WorkingArea;
        Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)(IntPtr.Size * 2 + m.LParam.ToInt64()), typeof(Rectangle));

        var DISTANCE = 0;

        if (rect.X <= workArea.Left + DISTANCE)
                Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2/*, workArea.Left*/);

        if (rect.X + rect.Width >= workArea.Width - DISTANCE)
                Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2/*, workArea.Right - rect.Width*/);

        if (rect.Y <= workArea.Top + DISTANCE)
                Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2 + 4/*, workArea.Top*/);

        if (rect.Y + rect.Height >= workArea.Height - DISTANCE)
                Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2 + 4/*, workArea.Bottom - rect.Height*/);
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

[Прилипание окна к краю экрана без задвигания окна за экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541472/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)

```
protected override void WndProc ( ref Message m ) {
    if (m.Msg == 0x0046 /* WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING */) {
        Rectangle workArea = SystemInformation.WorkingArea;
        Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)(IntPtr.Size * 2 + m.LParam.ToInt64()), typeof(Rectangle));

        if (rect.X <= workArea.Left + DISTANCE)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2, workArea.Left);

        if (rect.X + rect.Width >= workArea.Width - DISTANCE)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2, workArea.Right - rect.Width);

        if (rect.Y <= workArea.Top + DISTANCE)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2 + 4, workArea.Top);

        if (rect.Y + rect.Height >= workArea.Height - DISTANCE)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(m.LParam, IntPtr.Size * 2 + 4, workArea.Bottom - rect.Height);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Или [Привязка окна приложения к краям экрана и блокировка его перемещения](http://www.csharpcoderr.com/2012/10/winform-no-peremeshenie.html)

```
private int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1;
const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
const int HTCAPTION = 2;
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        int result = SendMessage(m.HWnd, WM_NCHITTEST, IntPtr.Zero, m.LParam);
        if (result == HTCAPTION)
            return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Для закрепления формы на краю экрана, необходимо указать при запуске формы, расположение вашего приложения:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //привязка формы к определенному месту экрана

    //верх правого угла экрана
    this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(width - this.Size.Width, 0);
}
```

Comment: Так, первый пример - то что надо! Но вот теперь нельзя задвинуть форму за монитор, а это не очень хорошо. Хотелось бы что бы она прикреплялась, но если дальше продолжаешь двигать форму, она продолжала двигаться за монитор.

Comment: обновлено......

Comment: Если просто закоментить последние параметры, то прикрепление исчезает полностью